# Remove backspaces and corresponding characters from file

Tags: backspace

I use "script" a lot to capture the commands & output of interactive sessions, but find the embedded control-characters make them pretty unreadable. It's easy to filter out the ^M etc., but I'd really like to remove the characters that the ^H were meant to remove.

A substitution equivalent [^H]^H would do this for one character, but it'd be slow to have to repeat it one-by-one. I think that some of the utilities have a way to extract the length of a match like (^H)+ but I'm hazy on how to apply it to the N previous [^H] characters.

Comment: I do see this other character ```^[[27m``` just before the ^H sequence, I think that's when I hit the <esc> key. I need to recognize this as separating the removed text from the corresponding ^H sequence.